# Values of a register after executing code

Tags: microcontroller, avr, alu

What are the values of `r16` and `r17` after executing this code?

```
ldi r16, 0x06    ;load immediate
ldi r17, 0x0c    ;load immediate
lsl r16          ;logical shift left
eor r16, r17     ;exclusive or
```

So I know that `r16 = 12` after the logical shift left, making it equal to `r17`. Does the exclusive or set `r16` to 0 and `r17` stays at 12? Or do they both get set to zero? Is the zero flag set?

Comment: that's not really an ALU question, is it? Maybe it's done by the ALU, but all you ask is for instruction specifics.

Answer (score 1):

From the obvious source, http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instructions.Arithmetic_and_Logic_Instructions.html :

> EOR  Logical Exclusive OR
>
> Rd = Rd EOR Rr

So yes, r16 gets overwritten, but r17 stays unchanged.

http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_EOR.html
even spezifies what happens with the Zero Flag in the status register: It's set to (¯ denoting the inverse,• denoting logical and)

> R7¯ • R6¯ • R5¯ • R4¯ • R3¯ • R2¯ • R1¯ • R0¯